# How can I replace my string into mysql.format?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a question about mysql.format.

I am trying to put my string variable into mysql.format depending on the condition in the if statement with Javascript.

For example.

```
var query = mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ?
                          , [isAlwaystrue ? 1 : 'emp_no = 1']
```

But with this approach, the query does not work well.

To find out the problem, look up the query for mysql.format as shown below.

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHRERE 'emp_no = 1';
```

It looks like emp_no = 1 is surrounded by a single dot.

I'll ask for help. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the logic easy to understand and do it the long way:

```
var query;
if (isAlwaystrue) {
    query = mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees`);
} else {
    query = mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_no = 1`);
}
```

Or you can try the shorter way, but make the code more confusing:

```
mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ${isAlwaystrue ? 1 : 'emp_no = 1'}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string literals you could change your statement to this

```
var query = mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ?
                          , ${isAlwaystrue ? 1 : 'emp_no = 1'}
```

Comment: is that right mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ?'
                          , ${isAlwaystrue ? 1 : 'emp_no = 1'})

Comment: don't forget to closer your statment with `; if you don't have more conditionals in your query

Comment: mysql.format(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ?' , ${isAlwaystrue ? 1 : 'emp_no = 1'}`);